# Run shutdown command in background after delay on windows

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I am trying to run a command on a windows machine running a python client program. It needs to return a value to the server before executing the command.

```
def shutdown():
    if OS_LINUX:
        os.system("sleep 10s && sudo shutdown &")
    elif OS_WIN:
        os.system(<What to put HERE>)
    return (1,"Shutting down")
```

As you can see, the unix command works just fine.

In the background, it runs sleep for 10 seconds and after that is done, it runs sudo shutdown. The function is allowed to return properly and the server gets notice that the client is shutting down BEFORE "sudo shutdown" is run.

However, on the windows side of things, I can't seem to run shutdown -s after a delay AND run it in the background.

This is what I have so far:

```
start /b /wait timeout 10 && shutdown -s
```

I have tried many variations of it: with/without /wait and /b, using ping instead of timeout, sending the output of ping/timeout to ">nul", etc.

This one has been the closest to what I want, but timeout takes over the command line until it is done, which doesn't allow my return statement to be covered in shutdown() before "shutdown -s" is run. This leaves the server hanging until it times out, which is not what I want the user to see, especially because I can't guarantee that the client didn't just loose connection at the same time the server told it to shutdown.

I might be able to solve the problem by throwing "timeout 10 && shutdown -s" in a batch script and running that in the background using os.system("start /b shutdown_script.bat"), but this client program needs to be just a single portable file for distribution reasons.

The solution is easy on unix, what am I missing on dos?

EDIT: Running os.system("shutdown -s") command (at least on win10) causes a screen to show to the user saying that the system will be shutdown. This allows my function to work properly and return a value to the server. This is NOT the case for other commands like hibernate ("shutdown -h"), and not necessarily the case on older version of windows either. The problem still remains for other commands, such as closing the client program remotely.

EDIT2: I also need to run commands for hibernate, and logoff. Shutdown -h and -l respectively. The -t parameter of shutdown only works with -s and -r (At least on windows 10)

Comment: `/l` (log off) and `/p` (power off) call [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868), without timeout support. `/h` (hibernate), if supported and enabled, is implemented via the `NtInitiatePowerAction` system call, without timeout support. `/s` (shutdown) and `/r` (reboot) call [`InitiateSystemShutdownEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376874), except `/s` paired with `/hybrid` calls [`InitiateShutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376872). Both support a timeout of up to 10 years.

Comment: You can use a common solution internal to Python such as a `threading.Timer` that executes the shutdown command via `subprocess.check_call`. If you're running `/s` or `/r`, which support a timeout with system-wide warning to users, then you can skip the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem using schtasks because shutdown only supports a timeout for /s and /r.

The python code adds a 1 minute offset to the current time (schtasks doesn't deal in seconds), then calls os.system("schtasks.....") with a /f parameter to avoid schtasks holding up the console asking for a y/n overwrite.

```
def get_time_offset(offset):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    offset_now = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=offset)
    offset_now_time = offset_now.time()
    future_time = (str(offset_now_time.hour) + ":" + str(offset_now_time.minute) + ":" + str(offset_now_time.second) )
return future_time

def sch_task(name, time, task):
    os.system("schtasks /create /tn \"" + str(name) + "\" /sc once /st " + str(time) + " /tr \"" + str(task) + "\" /f")
```

The final call looks like this:

```
sch_task("client_hibernate", get_time_offset(1), "shutdown /h")
```

It will run 1 minute after the call is made.

The only problem with this solution is that schtasks only has precision by the minute, so you can't schedule a task for less than a minute in the future.

I will probably write a multithreaded timer in python to run the command instead of relying on schtasks for windows and sleep for linux.

Answer (score 1):

This command work fine for me:

```
shutdown /t 10 /s
```

Comment: The /t option is not available with either the /l, /h, or /p options. It does not work with anything other than /s, for some strange reason.

Comment: What did you mean by "not available". Not listed in help? Command refuse it? What version of window?

Comment: I'm running Win10. Running shutdown /t with /h or /l does not run. Instead it lists the correct usage for the shutdown command (as if you ran "help shutdown"). [I can only find one source that says anything about running /t with /h or /l.](https://www.lifewire.com/shutdown-command-2618100)

Answer (score 1):

#Machine will shutdown in 10 seconds. Pl close all open apps.
#if NOT required -> Control+C
import os,time

```
try:
time.sleep(5)#waiting for CTRL+C
print("shuting down...")
os.system("shutdown /s /t 10")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
input("Enter any key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am taking that you the command window to display the timeout, and and as soon as the timer is up you want the `SHUTDOWN` command to execute and exit. Here is what I would do:

```
echo off
goto :a
cls

:a
cls
timeout 10 
cls

:b
cls
shutdown -s >nul 
cls
```

**YOU COULD ALSO USE THIS COMMAND IF YOU WANT A SHORTER VERSION:**

```
shutdown /t 10 /s
```